# Symfony: How to disable logging for access method

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I usually set the allowed methods via tag which returns 405 and logs error:

```
/**
 * @Method({'POST'});
 */
```

Is there a way how to set the logging level for **only** this action to info or not to log anything at all via some sort of configuration or another annotation?

Just side note:
The URL in question is used in JavaScript for Ajax calls but has been fallowed by search engine and created several error level warnings that had to be manually proceed. This problem has been dealt with to some extend however the question above still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it showed up. We had [ExceptionListener](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.html) already implemented so only what I had to do was change the handling of the exception there:

```
class CustomExceptionListener extends ExceptionListener {

    protected function logException(\Exception $exception, $message, $original = true) {
        $flattenException = FlattenException::create($exception);

        if (null !== $this->logger) {
           //...
                if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
                    $this->logger->info($flattenException->getMessage() . "\nStackTrace: ");
                } else if ($exception instanceof //...
            }
         // ...Rest of code omitted
    }
}
```